Is there a solution to create a document number in SQL?
I'm looking for a query to change the DocNum(image) when my MDK column becomes zero with order by idn4
what's the right query for my question?
SELECT [idn4],[MDK],
CASE
WHEN [MDK]<>0 THEN Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [idn4])  
ELSE NULL
END AS DocNum


try:
SELECT [idn4], [MDK],
  SUM(CASE WHEN [MDK] <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY [idn4]) AS DocNum
FROM your_table_name;

